# How to access an iframe via WebDriver when iframe has dynamic src

Tags: java, iframe, webdriver

I am trying to access text body of an email but that is inside iframe. I tried to access but it says `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: no such frame`.

Here's what I tried:

```
driver.get("http://mailinator.com/inbox.jsp?to=iframetesting007");
        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Testing")).click();
        List<WebElement> AlliFrameID = driver
                .findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
        System.out.println("Size " + AlliFrameID.size());
        try {
            driver.switchTo().frame(2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Test Passed")).click();
```

**HTML:**

```
<iframe src="rendermail.jsp?msgid=1397822858-103157770-iframetesting007&amp;time=1397822875545" frameborder="0" width="888" height="1200" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">&lt;/ifram&gt;</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to check an email using Selenium - this is not a good idea. It's better to use native java libraries (e.g javax.mail) and get the email over the POP3 or other protocol. It's simply much faster and more reliable way.

Now to answer your question - you should write:

`driver.switchTo().frame(1);` you got the wrong index (it should be 1 instead of 2). Alternatively you can do:

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'rendermail')]"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

I assumed that beginning of src (rendermail) is actually constant so you can focus on this constant part ignoring the remaining, dynamic part.

The second approach is usually better. It's more readable (you can see which frame is being accessed) and protectes you from the case where elements could be reordered for any reasons.

Comment: Second method worked but only when there is 1 second sleep before webDriver could the webElement.